# deserialize httpclient's content result yields intermittend null values

Tags: json, asynchronous, httpclient

I have a async method in a pcl:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string method) where T : EntityBase
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info($"RequestURL {_client.BaseAddress}{method}");

            var response = await _client.GetAsync(method);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return HandleResponse<T>(response); //this method just handles failures and logs the info in aspecial way
            }

            Log.Info($"Response {content}");

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"Making api request to {method}. --- {ex.ToString()}");
            return default(T);
        } 
    }
```

my handleresponse method:

```
 private T HandleResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : EntityBase
    {           
        var resultType = RequestResultType.Success;
        var message = "OK";

        switch (responseMessage.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                resultType = RequestResultType.Failure;
                message = "Unauthorised";
                break;
        }

        Log.Info($"StatusCode: {responseMessage.StatusCode}");
        Log.Info($"ResultType: {resultType}");
        Log.Info($"Message: {message}");

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), resultType, message);
    }
```

The object represented in `T` above:

```
public class TaskItemList: EntitBase
{
    public List<TaskItem> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have, is that this same method, when called, randomly returns T as null. Sometimes T is partially populated, with some of the properties being null

When i call the API via the browser, there is always a value.

I suspect that the response content is not yet completely formed by the time json is trying to deserialize it, but how does one handle this?

Comment: There's a bug in HandleResponse, post that code.

Comment: @usr i updated the question with the handle response code, however, even when removing the handleresponse section i still get this problem.

Comment: What if `content == "null"`? Use the debugger to see where exactly the null is introduced.

Comment: @usr if i add a breakpoint, then content is never null. The object returned (see updated post) contains a list of items. The object  ALWAYS contains the correct amount of TaskItems, however, some of them are null.

Comment: So T is not null? It's one of the Tasks elements that is null? So maybe the JSON contains null?

Comment: I have logging ion the API as well, and the response is always the same. The problem here, is the response being serialised is sometimes complete. I can see in my API log that the returned json is complete, but this method somehow does not always see all of it.

Comment: If the JSON was truncated deserialization would fail. The bug is not visible in this particular piece of code. How are you determining that there are null items (am I correct about that? You have not answered my questions.)? Place an assert: `Debug.Assert(Tasks.All(x => x != null));`. Does that assert ever fire? Can you reproduce the problem at all or is it random?

Comment: T is not null, some of the task elements are null, json does not contian null. If i add DEbug.Assert, and i click on referesh on my page, i get an error after about 4 or 5 refreshes. This is totally random though, sometimes its after 10, sometimes it is immidiatelly